# Windows 10 - Disable / Remove Share tab in File Explorer Ribbon?

Tags: windows-explorer

On Windows 10, I want to hide the Share tab in the File Explorer Ribbon. Is there any registry key, group policy, or file modification that will let me do this? Please note that I don't want to get rid of the Ribbon altogether, just this particular tab.

Comment: No sure about the tab specifically, but I've locked down file explorer options from within that tab with various different registry settings by denying `everyone` access to the reg key using Group Policy but here's a small snippet example and some settings I've locked down as such before for some ideas.... https://i.imgur.com/ioLPMXG.png

Comment: If such a solution would suffice in your environment, you can adjust to be more explicit than `Everyone` too by the way to restrict a certain group, etc.